# Go reports "undefined" for external package exported constant

Tags: go, undefined

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
    log.Print(gopacket.MaxEndpointSize)
    log.Print(pcap.MaxBpfInstructions)
}
```

When I run `go build` I get this:

```
./main.go:11: undefined: pcap.MaxBpfInstructions
```

But you can see `MaxBpfInstructions` right here: https://godoc.org/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap#pkg-constants

I feel this must be a stupid mistake, but I can't find it. Help?

Comment: Perhaps you the version of the package on your workstation is before [this commit](https://github.com/google/gopacket/commit/454403b95996efc4a90560627766832b8f1de151).  Run `go get -u github.com/google/gopacket/pcap` and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I just installed go and the package on this machine, so I doubt it's the case. But hey, I appreciate your observation, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was missing `libpcap-dev`. Now why Go or the package didn't throw a proper error message is beyond me.